# Create different tiers with different features for users (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backend, psql

Okay so I am trying to build this rails app that has 2 types of users every type of user has a different tier (Bronze, Silver, Gold). I have a bunch of features that are currently available for everyone but I would like to split them up and manage them from the admin panel. So for example the bronze tier will have a search feature and the silver tier will have the search feature and a couple of other features.

My question is what is the best and most efficient way to do this? How would I associate the search feature to a specific tier? and after I create a new feature how would I add it to the admin panel so I can associate it with a tier without hard coding (just in case I want to change the what tier has what feature later on)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you could about this.

The most simple, although maybe not most efficient is to simply have a property on the User model that tracks the User type or tier. So;

```
User.find(1).tier # = bronze
```

Would tell you what tier the user is on. This quickly becomes inefficient if you have loads of tier specific data. So data which is needed for the bronze tier, but isn't needed/wanted on any other tier. In which case you need to have different models to make sure that you don't have loads of empty fields in your database. So you would think that you could make the tiers subclasses of the user.

```
class BronzeUser < User
```

The problem with this is how it stored in the database. This uses what is called Single Table Inheritance, meaning that all your subclasses of User use the same table still. Although code-wise this method is nice, your database is on a good path to becoming unsustainable and unmaintainable.

In my opinion, the best way to tackle this problem is to have the user own their role. I.E. create user models that have a one-to-one relationship with a specific role model.

```
class Bronze < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
```

Even better than that (depending on the use case) would be to implement the role as a polymorphic association. Meaning you'd be able to call

```
User.find(1).tier
```

And get back a Bronze, Silver, Gold object depending on what the user is. Though if the data structure for each tier is different this could add a lot of confusion.

Hope that helps.